# SetOnItemClickListener not responding in custom ListView of android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am new to android,I am currently making a listview with custom list items,I want to do an action on Listview's item click event,I have searched so many similar threads with no luck,Can anyone help me to fix this.my code is as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_hdr"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="SELECT YOUR CITY"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_search"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_hdr"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/et_selector"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search"
        android:hint="City Or Postal Code"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_loc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_search"
        android:background="@color/grey_light"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_loc"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text=" My Location"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scr_location"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_loc"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_populcar_city"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text=" Popular Cities"
                android:textColor="@color/orange"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv_city"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_populcar_city" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_states"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lv_city"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="States"
                android:textColor="@color/orange"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv_state"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_states" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**adapter**

```
public class CityAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private final ArrayList<City> city;
    Integer selected_position = -1;


    public CityAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<City> city) {
        mContext = c;
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return city.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_city, parent, false);
        } else {
            v = (View) convertView;
        }
        TextView tv_city = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_city);
        tv_city.setText(city.get(position).getCity());

        return v;
    }
}
```

**activity**

```
lv_city.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Pref.setValue( SelectCity.this, Const.PREF_CITY_ID, cityList.get( position ).getCity_id() );
        finish();//finishing activity
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong class in listview item click

```
lv_city.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                Pref.setValue( SelectCity.this, Const.PREF_CITY_ID, 
                cityList.get( position ).getCity_id() );
                finish();//finishing activity
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**@quick learner's** was correct, But i put some idea for your ref..

- If you use custom adapter class, In my suggestion use setOnClickListener in custom adapter class this is better way to do this type of case!!

For example,

```
mViewHolder.MyUI.setOnClickListener
```